# How to access sharepoint files on task scheduler when not logged in

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have a powerflow setup saving certain email attachments to a sharepoint folder. Our sharepoint syncs to onedrive. I have a python script that takes these excel files, reworks them and saves them to a mySQL table. The script runs fine when I am logged in, but when adding them to a task scheduler task to run when i am not logged into the VM it doesn't run. The task is setup with highest privileges and to run when user is not logged in. I use pandas read_excel to access the files, i don't refer to the sharepoint address in my code. Is there a way to setup a sheduled task to run on the VM whether I'm logged in or not?

I've tried the script in powershell, creating a bat file that executes the script and running it in Anaconda, nothing works